# Erro na String.replace Java

Tags: java, string, replace

Estou com uma dificuldade em fazer funcionar o `String.replace("á","a")`

No meu caso eu digito *canadá* e quero a saída *canada*, porem na saída aparece no lugar do á um quadrado, como se ali estivesse um caractere inválido.

Comment: Isso ai nao é problema do java não é problema de codificação dos arquivos .java que a sua IDE ou editor de texto está criando. Veja, funciona perfeitamente: https://ideone.com/3d5Xps

Comment: Não fui eu quem negativou, até porque achei a duvida relevante e curiosa, mas seria legal você postar um print desse resultado que está ocorrendo na sua IDE.

Comment: A saída é essa: canad�

Comment: Então o problema é o que mencionei no primeiro comentario, com certeza. Verifique a codificaçao que a sua IDE ou editor de textos está utilizando para criar os arquivos `.java`.

Comment: Verifiquei aqui e realmente é um problema no NetBeans. Usando um compilador online funcionou. Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: [Como verificar no eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3751828/5524514) e [como verificar no netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24784421/5524514)

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente apos essa modificação! Obrigado!